# How to aggregate data by SQL?

Tags: sql

I am not a SQL developer, but I need to make a request to sample the movement of accounts for the last month, aggregate information by client country.

I could only create an sample database but I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do *in the question*.

Comment: Aggregate functions in SQL                                                                                                                                                                                      
`COUNT` counts how many rows are in a particular column.
`SUM` adds together all the values in a particular column.
`MIN` and `MAX` return the lowest and highest values in a particular column, respectively.
`AVG` calculates the average of a group of selected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't totally clear what you are looking for, but you will need to use an aggregate function like SUM or COUNT as well as using a GROUP BY depending on what you need.

Here is a sum of the amount of transactions by country as an example.

```
select country, sum(transactions.amount) as TOTAL_AMT
from clients as clients
inner join accounts as accounts
  on accounts.client_id = clients.client_id
inner join transactions as transactions
  on transactions.sender_account_id = accounts.account_id
group by country;
```